# Optimizing a String Range Search

Tags: swift, string, optimization

I am currently working on an algorithm to find all ranges of a target string.

Example:

```
Input: s = "acfacfacf", target = "acf"
Output: [(0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 9)]
Note: the upperBound is not an index of the subarray.
```

This is my current solution:

```
extension String {
    func allRanges(of string: String) -> [(Int, Int)] {

        var ranges = [(Int, Int)]()
        var set: Set<Int> = []
        let chars = Array(self)
        let target = Array(string)

        for index in 0..<chars.count {
            if chars[index] == string.first { set.insert(index) }
            for i in set {
                if index-i < target.count && chars[index] == target[index-i] {
                    if index-i == target.count-1 {
                        ranges += [(i, index+1)]
                    }
                } else {
                    set.remove(i)
                }
            }
        }

        return ranges
    }
}
```

This algorithm does well on strings like "acfacfacf" but does poorly on strings like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" where the target is "aaaaaaaa" and the expected result is:

```
[(0, 8), (1, 9), (2, 10), (3, 11), (4, 12), (5, 13), (6, 14), (7, 15), (8, 16), (9, 17)]
```

Are there any optimizations that can be done here?

Edit: Also. I understand that using tuples here is not very Swifty, but that is not my biggest concern here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214707/discussion-on-question-by-andy-optimizing-a-string-range-search).

Comment: Are you testing them in Playground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate your collection indices dropping the last n elements (the size of your collection minus one), check if the subsequence elements is equal to the other collection, if true return the range otherwise return nil:

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    func indices<C: Collection>(of collection: C) -> [Index] where C.Element == Element {
        let size = collection.count
        return indices.dropLast(size-1).filter {
            self[$0..<index($0, offsetBy: size)].elementsEqual(collection)
        }
    }
    func ranges<C: Collection>(of collection: C) -> [Range<Index>] where C.Element == Element {
        let size = collection.count
        return indices.dropLast(size-1).compactMap {
            let range = $0..<index($0, offsetBy: size)
            return self[range].elementsEqual(collection) ? range : nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

You can also try to optimize it using collection's method `starts(with:)` to avoid offseting the collection index on every single iteration:

```
func starts<PossiblePrefix>(with possiblePrefix: PossiblePrefix) -> Bool where PossiblePrefix : Sequence, Self.Element == PossiblePrefix.Element
```

---

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    func ranges<C: Collection>(of collection: C) -> [Range<Index>] where C.Element == Element {
        let size = collection.count
        return indices.dropLast(size-1).compactMap {
            self[$0...].starts(with: collection) ? $0..<index($0, offsetBy: size) : nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

Or zipping the lower and upper indices of the possible ranges:

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    func ranges<C: Collection>(of collection: C) -> [Range<Index>] where C.Element == Element {
        let k = collection.count-1
        return zip(indices.dropLast(k),indices.dropFirst(k)).compactMap {
            self[$0...].starts(with: collection) ? $0 ..< index(after: $1) : nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind explaining how this func returns and array including the ranges beyond index 0? Doesn't `indices.dropLast(size-1)` just return the first index?

Comment: Indices returns all elements indexes. DropLast just avoids the iteration beyond the size of the collection passed. Minus one it is because of the range upperbound being after the last index of the collection

Comment: ahh i see thanks, I was accidentally reading size as self.count

Comment: I think there is still room for optimization here. I added a solution below

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Leo's post. There appears to be some unnecessary work with performing `.start(...)` and then `index(...)`. This can be further optimized with

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {

    func ranges<C: RandomAccessCollection>(of collection: C) -> [Range<Index>] where C.Element == Element {
        let size = collection.count
        return indices.dropLast(size-1).compactMap { idx in
            var i = idx
            var match = false
            collection.drop { element in
                match = element == self[i]
                i = index(after: i)
                return match
            }
            return match ? idx..<i : nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A better option would be to zip the indices with the upper indices

Comment: hmm, do you mind updating your post with that proposal? I don't understand.

Comment: `return zip(indices.dropLast(size-1),indices.dropFirst(size-1)).compactMap {
            self[$0...].starts(with: collection) ? $0 ..< index(after: $1) : nil`

Comment: ahh, very elegant, nice